# Would it be useful to subclass Objective-C Block?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I was just daydreaming on how one could let a Block object also be a delegate, e.g. to UIAlertView. It's a bit weird, I admit. But would it be possible to add methods to a Block object? Could you access the captured variables in the method?

Comment: More likely, in the case of `UIAlertView`, you'll want to use something like [UIAlertView(Blocks)](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks).

Answer (score 1):

No. Block literals have a runtime class that is implementation-defined and decided by the compiler. You cannot control what class a block object has; therefore, you cannot make it an instance of a custom subclass.

Comment: ... in addition to which — in case somebody reads this and thinks "oh, so I just need to figure out the class at runtime — in the current implementation a stack block will mutate into a malloc block upon copy, but a global block is a global block for all time. So there's no _the_ class to know. Blocks change class depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

With [REKit](https://github.com/zuccoi/REKit), you can make a block to be executed when delegate method is called. It's not limited to `UIAlertView`. You can use REKit for all instances adopted to delegation pattern.
See "[Delegate itself](https://github.com/zuccoi/REKit#delegate-itself)" example of REKit.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is YES, but not tied to UIAlertView.

Imagine a class supplies a block as a network session completion handler. Now you need to subclass this class, and (among other things) add something to the handler.

You have to copy the original handler and add your code. Code duplication is a bad code smell. But I am not aware of a way of subclassing blocks. :(